# How can I avoid showing "#!/usr/bin/php" on PHP?

Tags: php, apache, shell, nginx, command-line-interface

I want PHP scripts to run both on command line and website (I use Apache and Nginx) so I put #!/usr/bin/php in the first line of my scripts but that appears on the website...

Comment: If you already use apache for serving PHP, just configure nginx as reverse proxy for apache.

Answer (score 22):

I solved the problem using output buffering.
My script now looks like this:

```php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
@ob_end_clean();
...
```

**Note:** There is no `?>` at the end of the file. This is actually a good practice when writing PHP scripts. This prevents any garbage text to be accidentally printed.

**Note:** The PHP documentation for [`ob_end_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php) says that:

> The output buffer must be started by ob_start() with
>   PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE and PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_REMOVABLE flags.
>   Otherwise ob_end_clean() will not work.

It seems that this is done automatically when PHP runs from command line.

Comment: Do you need an `ob_start();` as well? Probably worth mentioning.

Comment: This is beautiful.

Comment: Nice idea, but @Floris had a crucial point here. Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53271823/1479945), where I've addressed that issue.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to have `#!/usr/bin/php` in your code, just run CLI script using `php`, for example `php /path/to/file.php` or `/usr/bin/php /path/to/file.php`.

Comment: But if you want to create an executable script that can run from shell, you need to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

@ViliamSimko's [wicked trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6772836/1479945) is almost there, but, unfortunately, flawed. *(It did actually break my header-sending sequence, for instance, despite not polluting the output with the shebang.)*

**TL;DR, here's the fix<sup>*</sup>:**

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php @ob_end_clean(); if(ini_get('output_buffering')) ob_start();
...
```

or, less obscene-looking, but still just an euphemism for the same offense ;) :

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php if (ob_get_level()) { ob_end_clean(); ob_start(); }
...
```

*(And see also the "UPDATE" part below for perhaps the maximum we can do about this...)*

**Explanation:**

@Floris had a very good point in the comments there:

> Do you need an ob_start(); as well? Probably worth mentioning.

You sure do. But where? And when?

Cases to consider:

1. As Viliam said (and just confirmed it with PHP 7.2), the shebang is fortunately eaten by the `php` command itself, when you run your script with `php yourscript.php`, so the entire trick is redundant.
2. In web mode, it's actually config-dependent: if `output_buffering` is on in the config (and sure enough, it's usually on, but it's [not even the default](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php)), an `ob_start` has already been done *implicitly* at the start of the script (you can check it with `ob_get_level()`). So, we can't just abruptly cancel it with an `ob_end_clean` and call it a day: we *need to start another one, to keep the levels balanced!*
3. If `output_buffering` is off in the config, then, sad face, we are out of luck: `ob_get_clean()` does nothing, and the shebang will end up in the top of the page.

   Note: there *is no* fix for this one, other than turning it on.
4. In command-line mode, [the manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php)  about `output_buffering`:

   > This directive is always Off in PHP-CLI.

   But, instead of failing the same hopeless way as in 3., the implicit shebang cleanup (see 1.) saves the day.

---

* "Fix" in the sense that this audacious hack will work in a lot more cases. If you are in full control of your PHP env., it can be just fine (as is in my case). Otherwise, it can still break in lots of subtle ways unexpectedly (consider auto-prepended code, custom extensions, or other possible ways to control output buffering etc.). Also, for example, when `include`d from other scripts in CLI mode (where there's no buffering), [you are still out of luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859952/make-a-php-script-executable-from-cli-and-include-able): the shebang will show up in the output, no matter what (unless, of course, filtered out manually by the caller). Not only that, but it would also break up *your own buffering*, if you happened to have any, while including such a naughtified script.

---

**UPDATE:** Just for the fun of it, here's an "almost correct" version, which plays along nicely with an ongoing buffering, be it implicit or user-level:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
if (ob_get_level()) {
    $buf = ob_get_clean();
    ob_start();
    // Refill the buffer, but without the shebang line:
    echo substr($buf, 0, strpos($buf, file(__FILE__)[0]));
} // else { out of luck... }
```

Still only "almost" correct, as nothing can fix `output_buffering = 0` in web mode, and the "being included with no buffering" case can only be solved if the calling script adds an explicit `ob_start` - `ob_end_...` wrapping. Also, most of the caveats above still apply: various subtleties can still break it (e.g. the current output buffer must have the (fortunately default) `PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE` flag etc.).)

Answer (score 2):

I generally find it a good idea to separate logic from presentation.  When I do something like this, I put as much as possible in a library, and then write separate cli and web interfaces for it.

That said, calling it with the php command is probably an easier fix.

Comment: +1 for separation of logic.  Typically CLI and web will require separate interfaces (interacting with `$argv` instead of `$_GET` for example).  So there's no real need for the same *file* to be called from both.

Answer (score 0):

Call the script using the `php` command

Comment: It's true that you can run the script using `php` command. However, if you want to make an executable script (`chmod +x yourscript.php`) you need to add the hashbang (#!) to the first line of your script.

Answer (score -2):

The output buffering solution above is a hack. Don't do that.

First thing, you are actually better using the env command to determine which php is being used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Then give it permission to be executed by itself:

```
chmod +x myfile
```

So instead of calling 'php myfile', you now just run:

```
./myfile
```

From that folder. Hope this helps!

Comment: I assume the downvotes are because what you describe (making the file executable, and using a shebang line) is what the questioner is already doing. Except, he's ALSO sometimes calling the same file through a webserver. So, in the browser, the shebang line prints. He's asking for a workaround for that. The output buffering hack for that appears to be the only method.

Comment: yeah he shouldn't be doing that. Better having the executable CLI script requiring in another file with the actual logic, and getting his web page PHP to do the same, so they share the same code and the shebang wont show

Comment: Updating your answer with that suggestion might be a way to fix the downvotes (not that anyone ever seems to check if people fixed the answers they've fownvoted... *sigh*)