# make a PHP script executable from CLI and include-able?

Tags: php

Consider this:

```php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
class Foo {
        static function bar () {
                echo "Foo->bar\n";
        }
}
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
        Foo::bar();
}
?>
```

I can execute this from CLI, but when I `include` it in, say, a CGI-run PHP script, the shebang ends up in the output.

I like simple scripts *compact*: I guess I could put the `class` part in a separate "lib"-file and have a simple wrapper for CLI use. BUT I'd like to keep it all in one place without having to worry about include paths etc.

Is this possible without `ob_*`-wrapping the `include` to capture the shebang (if this is even possible), or is it dumb to cram all of this into one file anyway? Alternatives/Thoughts/Best Practices welcome!

Edit: I'd like to put the script in my `PATH`, so calling I'd rather not call it by `php file.php`. See my comment to @misplacedme's answer

Comment: You can get away without needing the shebang just make sure your call full paths to your php binary and it'll be fine

Comment: @Dave - isn't this what misplacedme answered? Sorry if I'm wrong, I don't really understand "your call full paths to"...

Comment: I know this is old, and @kubi, you don't seem to be hanging around here much, but if you still see this, just wondering: what have you ended up with? AFAIK it's not possible to solve this problem even today (PHP 7.2). It would need at least a new command-line option (and/or ini setting) to tell PHP not to output the shebang, if it exists.

Comment: Since this was more about convenience&curiosity than necessity I abandoned the issue, @Sz. And I do lurk here quite a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I'm rather late to this one, but if anyone still cares, you can solve this on Linux by registering a binfmt handler.
As a one-off (resets after reboot):

```
echo ":PHP:M::<?php::/usr/bin/php:" > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
```

With this in place, any file that starts with the "magic" string "<?php" will be executed by running it with /usr/bin/php.

You can make this registration permanent by saving the line a file in `/etc/binfmt.d`

You can remove the registration with:

```
echo -1 > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/PHP
```

Comment: this feels... cursed :)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually easy.
Remove the shebang and when you run the script, run it as
    `php scriptname.php`  OR `/path/to/php scriptname.php`
instead of
    `./scriptname.php`

Running `php script.php` will look in only the current directory, or any directory within PATH.  If you absolutely have to run it that way, add it.  `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/php/script/folder`(in bash)
That will mess up includes unless you're using full paths within the script.
No matter what you do, you'll have to use full paths somewhere.

Comment: Ah, I didn't mention that I want to have the script in my `PATH`. Something like `cat somefile | php /usr/local/share/foo.bar.php | sed …` is no fun.

Comment: Normally php is included in your path, or you can add it.  
Is neither option available to you?

Comment: php sure is, but my script isn't. Doesn't `php file` look for `file` only in working directory?

Comment: I added a little extra to my post.  The paths problem is a separate issue really.

Comment: yeah, this *sort of* works... I'll investigate how this affects a real-world case. Real-world weird edge case. Thanks!